# IntegrityError - NOT NULL constraint failed in the `models.DecimalField`

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm trying to build a `models.DecimalField` which will set to **50** and will have a range (from **50** to **9000**) with a step **50**. I have read that I can use [`choices`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/): *"A sequence consisting itself of iterables of exactly two items (e.g. [(A, B), (A, B) ...]) to use as choices for this field. If choices are given, they’re enforced by model validation and the default form widget will be a select box with these choices instead of the standard text field."*.

I have no idea how to fix it. For sure error is in `quantity      = models.DecimalField`.
My code:

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class ProductInquirie(models.Model):
    email         = models.CharField(null=False, blank=False, max_length=120) # max_lenght required
    tittle        = models.TextField(null=False, blank=False)
    quantity      = models.DecimalField(
                                        null=True,
                                        blank=True,
                                        decimal_places=0,
                                        max_digits=4,
                                        default=50,
                                        choices=[(i, i) for i in range(50, 9000, 50)]
                                        )
    target_price  = models.DecimalField(null=False, blank=True, decimal_places=2, max_digits=7) # Why decimal not float: https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html#module-decimal
    one_time      = models.TextField(default="client didn't provide information, or want constant supply")
    constant_need = models.TextField(default="no information")
    how_soon      = models.TextField(default="no information")
```

Error:
[image: NOT NULL constraint failed]

Expected behaviour:
It should look like this:
[image: default set]

Unfold, like this:
[image]
...but, without errors when saved(till now the error appears when the "save" button is pressed):)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was pointed out in the previous replies, quote:

```
target_price  = models.DecimalField(null=False, blank=True, decimal_places=2, max_digits=7)
```

So, the proper code would be:

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class ProductInquiry(models.Model):
    email         = models.CharField(null=False, blank=False, max_length=120) # max_lenght required
    tittle        = models.TextField(null=False, blank=False)
    quantity      = models.DecimalField(
                                        null=False,
                                        blank=False,
                                        decimal_places=0,
                                        max_digits=4,
                                        default=50,
                                        choices=[(i, i) for i in range(50, 9000, 50)]
                                        )
    target_price  = models.DecimalField(null=True, blank=True, decimal_places=2, max_digits=7)
    one_time      = models.TextField(default="client didn't provide information, or want constant supply")
    constant_need = models.TextField(default="no information")
    how_soon      = models.TextField(default="no information")
```

I want to add some tips to avoid similar problems in the future. I just found great charts about when to use `null` and `blank` in every situation. Charts are from the book **"Two Scoops of Django"** and they solve every typical case:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The error is about the `target_price`, there is nothing wrong with your `quantity` field (right now).

By setting the `blank=True`, it is not required in the admin panel. It is however a required field in your database, see `null=False`. This is what generates the error you have.

```py
target_price  = models.DecimalField(null=False, blank=True, decimal_places=2, max_digits=7)
```

Just add something to this field and it will work fine.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. To make the solution even more clear I posted cool charts in my reply below (I couldn't post it here).

Comment: You could also have edited it in your original post, the charts are indeed clearer than my attempt.

Answer (score 1):

```
target_price  = models.DecimalField(null=True, blank=True, decimal_places=2, max_digits=7)
```

This error is not about your `quantity` field.
Just change your `target_price` field, set its `null` attribute to `True`,  After that, run `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate` command. this will remove your **NOT NULL constraint failed** error.